# Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime, Lamda not supported

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am trying to load module dynamically inside dynamically loaded module like below

```
path: 'reports',
loadChildren: () => import('./report/report/report.module').then(m => m.ReportModule),
```

and I am getting the error while doing **npm run package** as

{"__symbolic":"error","message":"Lambda not supported","line":154,"character":18}

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `strictMetadataEmit` to `false` in `tsconfig.base.json`:

```json
{
  ...

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": false,
    ...
  }
}
```